# Consuming JWT authentication API in asp.net core blazor application

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor-server-side

I am looking for the most secure way to authenticate my Web App using an exiting API that is configured to issue JWT tokens.
The current setup:

1. Asp.net core API that is able to handle user management portion.
2. Asp.net core 5.1 blazor server app that is used to serve web pages on the client-side.
   Objective:
   I want the web app to have no access to database and use API for handling the backend logic.

One way to go around it would be to get JWT to save it a cookie

```
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
    {
        int minute = 60;
        int hour = minute * 60;
        int day = hour * 24;
        int week = day * 7;
        int year = 365 * day;

        options.LoginPath = "/auth/login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/auth/accessdenied";
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(day/2);

        options.Cookie.Name = "access_token";

        options.TicketDataFormat = new CustomJwtDataFormat(
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256,
            tokenValidationParameters);
    });
```

and pass it to every request

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", token, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = true, Secure = true });
```

I also know that there are a bunch of other methods that can be used to store tokens, such as local storage, so what would be the most secure way to go about handling login on the client-side?

Comment: If you don't require any of the server-side benefits to Blazor Server, why not switch to Blazor WASM instead? It requires API usage for everything.

Comment: @CoryPodojil I like the speed of the server-side version.

Comment: You mean you just like the first time visit loading speed? WASM is fast once it is installed.

Comment: @CoryPodojil yes, but the initial loading time is more, not a major issue but I am going for the optimal solution.

Comment: Ah yeah, well in that case, you will have to take the WASM approach and create some `HttpClients` to access your APIs. I still suggest checking out Blazor WASM if you haven't already to see what I am on about.